# Hotkey function to input text in a specific URL

Tags: javascript

I want to perform the following action.

When I open the URL `http://google.com`, if I press the keyboard combination (or hotkey) `Z` + `P` , then google should input in the searchbox `How to make userscripts` and when I press the keyboard combination (or hotkey) `Z` + `O` then google should input in the searchbox `How to run userscripts`

Please guide me as to how can I achieve this function as I am a complete novice
Thanks and regards, Vicky.

Edit: For the following code

```
document.onkeyup=functione{
  var e = e || window.event; // for IE to cover IEs window event-object
  if(e.altKey && e.which == 65) {
    alert('Keyboard shortcut working!');
    return false;
  }
}
```

For the above code, when `http://google.com` is loaded and I press the `Alt` + `A` button, a pop up should be there with `Keyboard shortcut working!`. How to put this up in Tampermonkey? Please guide. @evolutionbox

Comment: Use a tool like "tampermonkey"

Comment: @evolutionbox How to do it? can you please help me with a simple script for above function

Comment: Not really. We're here to help with code you've _already written_, not provide code for requirements. Please update the question with a [mcve]

Comment: Please do not post code updates in comments. Instead edit the question

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use a browser plugin like [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) for Firefox. Userscripts allow you to set rules so that they automatically run once those conditions are met. I wrote up a basic userscript that should be able to do what you requested. I tested it using tampermonkey and Firefox.

Note: It is probably more ideal to use key modifiers (shift, alt, ctrl) to create hotkeys with JavaScript, as the logic can be somewhat simplified, but hopefully this will give you something to play with.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Google HotKeys
// @version      0.1
// @include      https://www.google.com/
// @run-at document-end
// ==/UserScript==

//store the first condition as false to start
var firstCondition = false;

//change the input value
function performAction(s){
    document.querySelector(`[aria-label="Search"]`).value = s;
}
//listen for keydown event
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(firstCondition){
        //if first condition is true, then look for second condition
        if(e.key == "o"){
            //if o is pressed after z, then do this...
            performAction("How to run userscripts")
        }else if(e.key == "p"){
            //otherwise, if p is pressed after z, then do this...
            performAction("How to make userscripts")
        }
        //either way, reset the first condition
        firstCondition = false;
    }else{
        //if the first condition is false, then check if "z" was pressed
        firstCondition = e.key == "z";
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me to understand! @Jscrip